# Hive Partition Performance

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I would like to ask about Hive partitioning performance.
How many records (in term of rows) would I need in order to see the partitioning performance?

Currently, I have 2 million+ records and I have split the table into 2 partitions.
My partitioning condition is as follow:

- `ADD PARTITION (year_month=’2017_07’)`
- `ADD PARTITION (year_month=’2017_08’)`
- `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T PARTITION (year_month='2017_07')
  SELECT * FROM T WHERE st_time < '2017_08_01 00:00:00.0';`
- `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T PARTITION (year_month='2017_08')
  SELECT * FROM T WHERE st_time >= '2017_08_01 00:00:00.0';`

When I tried to do some performance testing between the partitioned table and non-partitioned table, the performance of both tables is relatively the same.
My performance testing query is as follows:

- `SELECT * FROM T WHERE st_time < '2017_08_01 00:00:00.0';`
- `SELECT * FROM non_part_table WHERE st_time < '2017_08_01 00:00:00.0';`

Am I missing out on some important points?

Also, does partition work on derived column/function? E.g. date_format(st_time, yyyy-MM)

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the performance of both tables is relatively the same

You forgot the WHERE clause against the partition. Partitions only improve performance when you are selecting data *within them*.

```
SELECT * FROM T 
WHERE year_month = '2017_07'
-- AND st_time < '2017_08_01 00:00:00.0'
;
```

Without this, you're still scanning the whole table for the `st_time` values.

You can add an `EXPLAIN` to the queries to see the difference

You'll get additional performance improvements by converting data into Parquet or ORC

Comment: Hi cricket_007, thank you so much for your help! Does partition work for function? E.g. I define the partition to be year_month = '2017_07' and my year_month column in my table is a timestamp data type.  I use date_format(year_month, yyyy_MM) in my WHERE clause, does it consider selecting data within the partition?

Comment: Your partition is already `2017_07`... What is the purpose of the date_format? I mean, sure, like `concat('2017', '_07')` might work

Comment: Hmmm, what you said make sense. Thank you so very much for helping me with my problem! Good day sir!

Comment: In fact without the appropriate `WHERE` clause(s), `partitioned` tables would actually worsen the read performance. Isn't it **@cricket_007**?

Comment: @y2k-shubham The point of including the `WHERE` is to prune the partitions and the data that is scanned, so yes? But having a partitioned table and not filtering based on them isn't any different than not having partitions at all